# Advanced textbox merging in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, merge

Is there a way to merge textboxes like this :

```
textbox1 : O N E
textbox2 : T W O
```

So when i merge it it looks like:

**O T N W E O**

Comment: why dont you create your own sub by concatenate char in the textbox ?

Comment: It always merges like "ONETWO",not like i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a loop for your textboxes text ..

```
Function MyMerge(byval string1 as string, byval string2 as string) as string
Dim x as Integer iif(string1.Length >= String2.Length, String2.Length, String1.Length )
For i as Integer = 1 to x
  MyMerge &= iif(string1.length >= x, string1.substring(i-1,1),"") 
  MyMerge &= iif(string2.length >= x, string2.substring(i-1,1),"")
Next

End Function
```

So, you may use this by ..

```
Msgbox(MyMerge(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text))
```

Comment: it is just "text mixer".One writes word in both textbox1 and 2,anb button should merge that two textboxes.

Comment: I just added return(mymerge) and it works now.Thanks for your time.